# Understanding quaternions and axis angle representations

Tags: rotation, quaternions

I have a sensor that gives me a quaternion. I convert the quaternion to an axis-angle representation using http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToAngle/. When I hold the sensor on a flat surface and rotate the sensor pressed against the flat surface, I would have expected the axis to be the same and the angle to vary from 0-360 degrees - but this does not happen (the axis varies significantly). Any ideas why? Maybe I don't understand the axis-angle representation?

Comment: It depends on what is considered the original orientation of the sensor. If the flat surface is not perfectly aligned to two axis for the default orientation then the axis will change as you rotate.

Comment: How does the original orientation of the sensor matter? If the flat surface is not aligned to the default orientation, then the axis might not be something nice like [0,0,1] but maybe [0.01.. 0.01.. 0.99..]. It shouldnt change as I rotate the sensor?

Comment: It will change, because the axis isn't the one you are currently rotating around, it is the axis that you need to rotate around to get from the original orientation to the current orientation.

Comment: So if you rotated the sensor at all from it's default orientation to get it on to the flat surface, then rotating it on the surface will change the angle of rotation from it's original orientation.

Comment: okay that makes sense. So how do i get the axis i am currently rotating around from the quaternion?

Comment: so the quaternion gives me the axis to rotate around to get from the original to the current orientation + the angle about this axis to rotate. When on the flat surface, I rotate the sensor, the axis and angle both change because that transformation is changing. So how would I get a non-changing axis, but a changing angle?

Comment: I think you could get the quaternion before you start the rotation (once the sensor is on the surface) and subtract it from your current quaternion during your rotation, to get the difference between the two orientations, which will have the axis and angle of your rotation on the surface.

Comment: The difference between the two quaternions would give me the axis and angle of rotation? How does that work?

Comment: The difference between the two orientations would just include the rotation since you placed the sensor on the surface, since you are subtracting out all the rotations up to that point.

Comment: Intuitively that makes sense, but I'm not sure if that would work. Say I'm rotating about the z-axis by 30 degrees. When I start, I get [w x y z] from the sensor. If what your saying is true, then when I rotate about z by 30 deg, I should get [w + cos(15), x, y, (z + sin(15))] ?

Comment: Sorry, when I said subtract I meant divide (the inverse of multiplication which is how quaternions stack up naturally). So basically find the inverse quaternion when your sensor is on the surface, then multiple your current quaternion that to get the difference between the two rotations.

Comment: So if q0 is the original quat when my sensor is on the surface, and q1 is the next reading, I do q1 * inv(q0) or inv(q0) * q1?

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to work. In pseudocode, I get the quaternion inverse [w, -x, -y, -z] when the sensor is on the table. Then for all subsquent motions, I compute a new quaternion as q1 * inv(q0) and then convert this new quaternion to an axis/angle form. When I do so, the axis is still varying.

Comment: Is the quaternion normalized?

Comment: yes it is. So inv(q0) = conj(q0). I was wondering what would happen if I rotate the sensor to the original location -> in that case I should get an axis of [0,0,0] right? Because I would be doing q0 * inv(q0) ? So if this method worked, I'd have a fixed axis everywhere except at the original location?

Comment: Yeah that's right, at the original location there is no rotation to represent so the axis is undefined.

Comment: i think you should do inv(q0) * q1. in fact on the surface is q0 after you rotate inv(q0) * q1 and you find q0 * inv(q0) * q1 = q1. The order of multiplication is important, cause multiplication in quaternion is not commutative (as matrices and rotations in space).